# MailChimp API http request

Tags: angularjs, curl, mailchimp

I want integrate mailchimp api in my web app.

The docs is here: 
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#before-you-start

How to translate Curl in Http request? (Angular JS)

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/' \
--user 'anystring:<your_apikey>'
```

This "--user" is string in url or headers?

Sorry about my bad english. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you'll inject the $http service and call it

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  //this key comes from Mail Chimp
  $scope.myApiKey = "2039rslkdjf=34$#34098-us15";
  $scope.endOfKey = "us15";
$http.get({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://' + $scope.endOfKey + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
      authorization: 'anystring ' + $scope.myApiKey
    })
    .then((response) => {
      //do something once it comes back
     })
    .error((error) => {
      //do something in case there's an error
     })
    .finally(() => {
      //do something after either success or error
     })
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you Cameron! I don´t know about "user" parameter in http request.

Comment: The user parameter will be your api key that you get from MailChimp. It lets them know it's you (Vinicius) calling them. You can find how to get one here (http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/about-api-keys). They use the api key to track how many requests you make to them to make sure it's not too often. Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @ViniciusCésar I went ahead and created a mailchimp account to test everything. I made some changes to my answer based on what I found